# Use maven profile properties in application.conf

Tags: java, maven, ninjaframework

In my pom.xml file, I have multiple profiles set up. I would like to use the current profile's values in my application.conf file. The Ninja Framework documentation only mentions [mode configurations](http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/configuration_and_modes.html), however I can't find anything concerning profile configurations.

An example: The documentation mentions

```
database.name=database_production   # will be used when no mode is set (or prod)
%prod.database.name=database_prod   # will be used when running in prod mode
%dev.database.name=database_dev     # will be used when running in dev mode
%test.database.name=database_test   # will be used when running in test mode
```

How would I be able to set different database names depending on the currently used profile?

Comment: For Ninja Framework specifically:

1) application.conf needs to be filtered

2) in application.conf put

db.connection.url=${dburl}

3) For each profile, put 

<dburl>jdbc:postgresql://dbIp:dbPort/dbName</dburl>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add whatever it is you want replaced as a property to your profile definition, and then enable maven resource filtering like this:

```
<build>
  ..
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ..
</build>
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>developmentProfile</id>
    <properties>
      <dbName>database.name=database_dev</dbName>
    </properties>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>productionProfile</id>
    <properties>
      <dbName>database.name=database_prod</dbName>
    </properties>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Be careful, if you use **spring-boot**, you should reference the properties in the **application.properties** file like this for it to work:

```
someOtherProp = something
@dbName@
```

After that, building the app should filter the property correctly:

```
mvn clean install -PdevelopmentProfile
```

Result:

```
someOtherProp=something
database.name=database_dev
```

Comment: So what lines go into the application.conf file? None? The same as in application.properties? Some property reference combination?

Comment: Yes, application properties was just an example because spring-boot needs special consideration. For any other file, be it .conf or any other you just put the property to replace. For other than spring boot, you might use the property like `${dbName}`.
Wherever the resources plugin encounters the `dbName` property (either with `${}` or `@@` brackets in case of spring-boot, it will replace it with the property from your profile definition in `pom.xml`
I edited the answer for formatting reasons, it might be easier to read.